# Kibana Tile Map Doc_Count Filter

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, kibana-4

I have a tile map that looks at the average value of X in each region. At certain zooms there are only 1-2 users, so the average doesn't mean much. Is it possible to add a filter that removes tiles for regions that have less than n users?

Comment: I noticed the response JSON has doc_count for each geohash bucket, but I can't figure out how to filter on that.